# How to achieve jQuery scrolling/overlay effect (video in description)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two columns.

The left column contains text of dynamic lengths.

The right column is of fixed height and will contain a set of images selected at random per page load.

I am trying to create an effect where while the user scrolls, the *Image 2* scrolls above *Image 1*. When it reaches the top, the *Image 1* begins to scroll up until it disappears, then *Image 3* comes in and repeats the process.

As this is rather confusing, I made a short video describing the desired effect.

[Video - MP4](http://cloud.alanwoo.ca/Zedo)

I have begun trying to get it working in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eqixiv/2) but am at a loss for when the user scrolls back down and also when more images are required. I am thinking my current path is not the right direction. I'm thinking that employing something like jQuery waypoints is more the direction I should be pursuing?

Comment: Your video link is not working.  Also, could you possible create this example of JSFiddle?  It would be a lot easier for people to see what's going on :)

Comment: Hi, I fixed the video link, the example is in the jsbin above.